# Капча в виде примера

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, знатоки.

Пытаюсь изобразить что-то типа капчи, вот код:

```
<?php
session_start();
    $n1 =  rand(1,100);
    $n2 =   rand(1,9);
    $op = '+';
//$total = $n1+$n2;
//echo $total;
$error = '';
if (isset($_POST['registration'])){
    if(isset($_POST['captcha']) && !empty($_POST['captcha'])){
        $captcha = htmlspecialchars($_POST['captcha']);
        //$total = $n1+$n2;
        //$total = $_SESSION[$total] = $total;
$captcha = $_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha;
        if($captcha == $n1+$n2){
            //$total = $n1+$n2;
            //$_SESSION[$total] = $total;
            //echo $total;
            echo 'Вы успешно зарегистрированы';
        }else $error .="Что-то не так";
    }else $error .= "Вы не решили примерчик<br>";

}
echo $error;
?>
Решите пример: <br />
<form action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>' method='POST'>
<?php
echo "<b><font color='blue'>".$n1." ".$op." ".$n2." = </font>";
?>
<input type='text' name='captcha' size="2" /><br></b>
<input type='submit' value="ok" size="2" name='registration'/>
</form>
```

Проблема в том, что не могу сверить результат `$captcha == $n1+$n2`, так как при вводе ответа и запросе, обновляется значение `$n1+$n2`. Например, 4+1, это будет 5, но если пользователь введет 5-ку и нажмет ок, то выдаст о том, что "что-то не так" ибо обновляеться страница и пример тоже обновляется допустим на 7+1, и уже будет 8, а не 5. Как можно вернуть предыдущее значение `$n1+$n2`?

Comment: Ух, блин! Вы сначала алгоритм формирования и проверки капчи распишите, а потом уже "переведите" на язык программирования. Тут столько ошибок, что проще код переписать с нуля.

Comment: Я вижу мастера, познавшего Дзен))

    $captcha = $_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha;

Answer (score 1):

> как можно вернуть предыдущее значение $n1+$n2?

Его не "возвращать" надо, а передавать на сраницу с капчей в сессии или в куках. При отправке формы - доставать и проверять. На всякий случай: передавать, конечно, не сам ответ, а его md5, sha1 etc.

Comment: Значит, примерно этот код. Немного, конечно, кое-что поменять и в новый файл вставить? Просто я не хочу пользоваться разными функциями, которые создают картинку для капчи

    session_start();
    $n1 =  rand(1,100);
    $n2 =   rand(1,9);
    $op = '+';
    $error = '';
    if (isset($_POST['registration'])){
        if(isset($_POST['captcha']) && !empty($_POST['captcha'])){
            $captcha = htmlspecialchars($_POST['captcha']);
    $captcha = $_SESSION['captcha'] = $captcha;

Comment: Я бы вообще не стал знакомиться с вещами, которые применять не нужно :) Капча, если уж так хочется свои проблемы решать засчёт неудобств для пользователей (а лишние действия, особенно распознавание картинки - это неудобства на 100%), должна быть такая, чтобы этих самых неудобств пользователям не создавать, во завернул!

Answer (score 0):

Такая капча обходится в минуту. Попробуйте хотя бы [**w3captcha**](http://w3box.ru/captcha/).

**UPD:**

Смотрите тут: [**Простая математическая капча**](http://govnoproger.ru/php/prostaya-matematicheskaya-kapcha.html).

Comment: exec, ну только ради чтобы посмотреть как сравнить. хочу свою )) спасибо